# ListView showing incorrect layout height

Tags: react-native

I am trying to scroll to a specific position in the ScrollView. This is what I have:

```
<ScrollView>
   {child components laid out using map}
</ScrollView>
```

when I check height using onContentSizeChange, I see that the height of the scrollview is changing correctly. However, onLayout shows a different height.

Lets call height from onContentSizeChange is X and height from onLayout is Y and X > Y.

When I trigger scrollviewref.scrollTo(X) or scrollToEnd, scrollview is scrolled to position Y not X. How can I fix this issue?

I do not know how to fix scrollview layout height. ScrollView is working perfectly fine when manually scrolling. It is just that I cannot get scrollToEnd() to actually scroll to the bottom.

Comment: Could you provide a minimally viable source code so that we can repeat the issue that you are witnessing?

Comment: This is example of what I have although I am not sure this is repeatable.

`let someList = [];
for (let i=0;i<10000;i++) someList.push(i);

return <ScrollView>
   someList.map((obj)=> return <Text>obj</Text>
</ScrollView>;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing to fix. What you have observed is expected behavior.

The height obtained from `onLayout` is the height of the scroll view as displayed on the screen (**view height**). The height obtained from `onContentSizeChange` is the total height of the content (**content height**). If there are 20 elements in the content and each content has height of 50, the `onContentSizeChange` height would be 20 * 50 = 1000, regardless of how the apparent height of the scroll view is on the screen.

The view height and content height has no correlation. The function `scrollTo` only considers the offset from the top of the content (assuming the scroll view is vertical). That's why calling `scrollToEnd` scrolls to the content height, which is the largest offset possible.

You can play with this [Snack Example](https://snack.expo.dev/@fanchenbao/scrollview-scrollto) (try scrolling to 100, 500, 525, etc.) to have a better grasp of the scroll view mechanics.